# Get the last inserted time for more then one modal class in DRF

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get the response inserted time of more then one modal class and send in the response in DRF. For example, my modal class is:

```
class FeedVehicle(models.Model):
    sensor = models.ForeignKey(
        'SensorDevice',
        on_delete = models.CASCADE
    )
    feed = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class FeedElsys(models.Model):
    sensor = models.ForeignKey(
        'SensorDevice',
        on_delete= models.CASCADE
    )
    feed = models.TextField(null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I was writing the view as such but not able to succed

```
class LastFeedAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser, permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = serializers.DashboardSerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        weather_r712 = models.FeedVehicle.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:1]
        weather_r712_searlializer = serializers.SignalFeedSerializer(weather_r712, read_only=True)
        weather_r718 = models.FeedElsys.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:1]
        weather_r718_serializer = serializers.WeatherR718FeedSerializer(weather_r718, read_only=True)
        response = {"r712":weather_r712_searlializer.data, "r718":weather_r718_serializer}
        return Response(response)
```

I want to get the response of both modal last inserted time. I have created the serializer class But not sure how I will connect and get the response. Any Suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate `class` to get the response inserted time of more then one modal class, like below :

```
class HomeAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):

        #get signal_data data
        data = models.FeedVehicle.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:1]
        signal_ser = SignalFeedSerializer(data, many=True)
        signal_data = []

        for record in signal_ser.data:
            _id = record["id"]
            feed = record['feed']

            signal_data.append({"id":_id, "feed":feed})

        #get weather_data
        data = models.FeedElsys.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:1]
        weather_ser = WeatherR718FeedSerializer(data, many=True)
        weather_data = []

        for record in weather_ser.data:
            _id = record["id"]
            feed = record['feed']

            weather_data.append({"id":_id, "feed":feed})

        return Response({"signal_data":signal_data, "weather_data":weather_data})
```